# Configure charset for ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017, wine

I'm running a Windows application on Linux under Wine, that accesses a SQL Server using the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, for Linux.

It runs fine except that I see incorrectly represented the varchars with non-Ascii characters. The `nvarchar` fields (unicode strings) have no problem.

Example:

```
select rtrim('Presentación   ')
```

Returns: `PresentaciÃ³n`

My database has the encoding for varchars defined as iso8859-1, and Wine seems to use the cp1252 page code.

My guess is that the ODBC driver for Linux retrieves correctly the data and transforms them to UTF8, which runs fine (I can see the values correctly if I run my queries directly through `isql`), but when those strings are passed to my application, under Wine, they must be considered as cp1252 and that's when I see them incorrectly.

Has anyone had the same problem? what could I try?

Thank you.